# UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: always returns white unless one argument is 0

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I am using

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:136 green:155 blue:218 alpha:1.0];
```

to change the background color of my table view cells.

But for some reason the background just stays white. If I try

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:155 blue:218 alpha:1.0];
```

the color changes. This does not make sense to me. Any advice or tips?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The parameter aren't a values of 0 to 255 but a float between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:155.0f/255.0f blue:218.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Such a design goes all the way back to Quartz in early Mac OS X, and the idea was to provide prefectly future-proof, device-independent color space.

Comment: What difference does the f make in 155.0f

Comment: f specifies that 155.0 should be interpreted as a float rather than a double.

Answer (score 3):

The values need to be floats (in the range 0.0 to 1.0), not ints (in the range 0 to 255).

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

Try:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:155.0/255.0 blue:218.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The params are not integers but floats, so
you probably want to divide all color float values with 255.
Like this:

```
  [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255 green:155.0/255 blue:218.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

That's why the color changes when you set red to 0 instead of 1 which 136 means in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Set navigation bar to transparent in iOS 11**

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```